# Automatically map foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I use Automapper and code-first EF6 in a WebApi2 project. I have model classes as POCO, with an `EntityTypeConfiguration` class for each model class.

I also have DTO classes. These classes do not expose the foreign key properties and I tell Automapper to ignore foreign keys.

An example would be:

```
public partial class UserGroupModel
{
    public UserGroupModel()
    {
        this.Users = new List<UserGroupUserModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserGroupUserModel> Users { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserGroupUserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroupModel { get; set; }
    public virtual UserModel { get; set; }
}
```

So, the DTO class would look like this:

```
public partial class UserGroupUserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroupDto { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDto { get; set; }
}
```

As entities are detached when mapping from DTO to Model, and because the DTO classes do not have the foreign key properties (in this case `UserGroupId` and `UserId`, the value of these properties is always 0. So before calling `SaveChanges`, I have to do:

```
public override UserGroupModel Update(UserGroupModel entity)
{
    entity.Users.ToList()
                .ForEach(x => {
                    x.UserGroupId = entity.Id;
                    x.UserId = x.User.Id;
                });

    //Update db here...
}
```

Is there a better to handle this scenario? Would maybe annotating properties create clearer code?